# How to create a composite primary key with fluent api that contains a DayOfWeek column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, dayofweek, ef-fluent-api

In my model I have a detail table that will contain data for each day of the week, so it has this definition:

```
public class JournalDay
{
    public int JournalID { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan From { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan To { get; set; }

    public virtual Journal Journal { get; set; }
}
```

In the EF Fluent API mapping class I define the composite key like this:

```
HasKey(jd => new { jd.JournalID, jd.Day });
```

But the table structure generated by Entity Framework only has the first column in the primary key:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Journals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JournalID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Is this problem caused by the second column being a DayOfWeek enum ?? I've used enums before on composite keys and it never gave this problem

Comment: Did you try to cast enum to underlying type? e.g. `HasKey(jd => new { jd.JournalID, (byte)jd.Day });` (or int).

Comment: @abatishchev that syntax gives an error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator, when I've used enums it's not necessary to do that casting

Comment: Yes but it's simple to fix: `HasKey(jd => new { jd.JournalID, Day = (byte)jd.Day });`. What will be the result?